# I cannot figure out why buttons in my .kv file are not changing with python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am new to programming in kivy and using chatgpt helped me a lot, currently Im stuck at changing text on a button in kivy file from python file and chatgpt is even more confused than Iam.

The code should generate 2 incorrect and one correct translation to a word randomly taken from an array, put those words onto buttons in kivy gui and after clicking on one of them check if the aswer is correct.

.py

```
vocab = {
    "ability": ["schopnost", "cane", "chien"],
    "able": ["být schopen", "gatto", "chat"],
    "about": ["o", "maison", "casa"],
    "above": ["nad", "albero", "arbre"],
    "abroad": ["zahraničí", "libro", "livre"],
    "absorb": ["vstřebat", "assorbire", "absorber"],
    "abuse": ["zneužití", "abuso", "abus"],
    "accept": ["přijmout", "accettare", "accepter"],
}

class WordGame(BoxLayout):
    def generate_word(self):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.words = list(vocab.keys())
            self.generate_word()
        word = random.choice(self.words)
        translations = random.sample(vocab[word], k=3)
        correct_translation = random.choice(translations)
        self.ids.word_label.text = word
        self.ids.button1.text = translations[0]
        self.ids.button2.text = translations[1]
        self.ids.button3.text = translations[2]
        self.correct_button = {
            self.ids.button1: translations[0],
            self.ids.button2: translations[1],
            self.ids.button3: translations[2]
        }[correct_translation]

    def check_translation(self, instance):
        self.generate_word()
        if instance.text == self.correct_button:
            self.ids.word_label.text = "Correct!"
        else:
            self.ids.word_label.text = "Incorrect!"
        self.generate_word()
    
kv_files = ['splash.kv', 'login.kv', 'menu.kv', 'levelselect.kv', 'levelb1.kv', 'Charakter.kv', 'test.kv']


class Aplikace(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        global obraz
        obraz = ScreenManager()
        for file in kv_files:
            obraz.add_widget(Builder.load_file(file))
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        return obraz
    
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.login, 1)
    def login(*args):
        obraz.current = "login"
    def levelselect(self):
        obraz.current = "levelselect"
    def log(self):
        obraz.current = "menu"
    def Event(self):
        obraz.current = "splash"
    def levelb1(self):
        obraz.current = "levelb1"
    def Forum(self):
        obraz.current = "splash"
    def Friendlist(self):
        obraz.current = "splash"
    def Leaderboard(self):
        obraz.current = "splash"
    def Charakter(self):
        obraz.current = "charakter"
    def test(self):
        obraz.current = "test"

    
Aplikace().run()
```

.kv

```
<WordGame>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 1, 1
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"horizontal"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint_x: 1
            size_hint_y: 0.4

            Label:
                id: "word_label"
                text: "Click the correct translation"
                font_size: "24sp"
                bold: True
                text_size: self.width, None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Button:
                size_hint_y: 0.4
                id: button1
                text:
                on_release: root.check_translation(self)
            Button:
                size_hint_y: 0.4
                id: button2
                text:
                on_release: root.check_translation(self)
            Button:
                size_hint_y: 0.4
                id: button3
                text:
                on_release: root.check_translation(self)

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2

Screen:
    name: "test"
    WordGame:
```

Comment: Don't use quotes for an `id`. Try changing `id: "word_label"` to `id: word_label`

Comment: @JohnAnderson unfortunately not the solution. Ids on my buttons are not in quotes and still dont change, my best guess is that the screen itself is generated before class Wordgame. could that be the issue ? Thank you for responding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WordGame` class looks malformed. You have an `__init__()` method defined inside a `generate_word()` method. Plus, in your `__init__()` method, you try to access the `ids` of the `WordGame` class. But the `ids` have not yet been created when the `__init__()` method is run. The fix for that is to use `Clock.schedule_once()` to delay that access. Here is a modified version of your `WordGame` class that addresses these issues:

```
class WordGame(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.words = list(vocab.keys())
        Clock.schedule_once(self.generate_word)
        # self.generate_word()

    def generate_word(self, *args):
        word = random.choice(self.words)
        .
        .
        .
```

There are other issues (as I mentioned in my comment above), but hopefully this will get you started.